# Is the derivative of the conditional expectation of Y on X equal to the least squares projection?

Tags: probability-theory

Fix a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$. Let $Y,X$ be random variables from $\Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Let $m(x): \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be defined by $\mathbb{E}[Y|X=x]$. For readers not satisfied with this definition of $m(x)$, I justify it at the end of the post.

Suppose the derivative $m'(x)\vert_{x=\mathbb{E}[X]}$ exists. Is it true that $m'(x)\vert_{x=\mathbb{E}[X]}$ equals the least squares projection coefficient
$$ \beta \equiv \frac{\mathbb{E}\left[\left( X-E[X] \right) \left( Y - E[Y] \right) \right]} {\mathbb{E}[X^2]}$$
of $Y$ on $X$?
I conjecture this since by a previous theorem, $\beta$ is the coefficient on $X$ in the best affine approximation to $m(X)$ w.r.t. mean squared error.
And can we say anything about higher order derivatives of $m(x)$ at $x=\mathbb{E}[X]$?

#### More on the definition of m(x):

Let $Z=\mathbb{E}[Y\vert \sigma(X)]$ be a conditional expectation of $Y$ given $\sigma(X)$. Thus $Z$ is a random variable from $\Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ measurable w.r.t. $\sigma(X)$, the sigma algebra generated by $X$; I write this as $Z \in \sigma(X)$. If I'm not mistaken, since $Z\in \sigma(X)$, the [Doob-Dynkin Factorization Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doob%E2%80%93Dynkin_lemma) implies that there exists a Borel-measurable function $g: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $Z = g \, \circ X$.

We then define $m(x)=g(x)$.

$m(x)$ is not necessarily unique since the conditional expectation $Z$ is only unique up to measure zero, but I suppose this means $m(x)$ is essentially unique in some sense (not quite sure).

Thank you.

Comment: Is your "Aside" meant to suggest that people who aren't super rigorous would define $\mathbb E[Y|X]$ differently? Or that they wouldn't define it at all, just attacking the question without knowing what it's about?

Comment: It seems you are confusing several things. For example, $X:\Omega \to \mathbf{R}$ and $E(Y \mid X)$ can either be thought of being defined on $\mathbf{R}$ (it seems you do this) or being defined on $\Omega.$ But if it is defined on $\Omega,$ then the derivative makes no sense. Now, what do _you defined_ the least squares projection to be? The formula you wrote is a constant, you cannot minimise that. Finally, if $X$ is real-valued, then its span is all of $\mathbf{R}$ unless $X$ is the constant random variable equal to zero (a.s.).

Comment: Thanks for the comments folks. I've revised the question now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following joint density, $f(x,y)$, of $X$ and $Y$:

$\hspace{1.5cm}$[image]

Here, $\mathsf{E}[X]=-1/3$ and $m(x)=0.5 + 1_{[0,1]}(x)\cdot x$ so that $m'(\mathsf{E}[X])=0$, but $\operatorname{Cov}(X,Y)> 0$.

Comment: Thanks so I guess the conjecture only holds if $m(x)$ is affine. The problem appears to be that $\operatorname{Cov}(X,Y)$ incorporates global information about the joint distribution, while $m'\left( \mathbb{E}[X] \right)$ is determined only by local information.